# How to retrieve Node names in Firebase without iterating through the snapshot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data looks like below,

```
"USERS": { "JACK": { "FirstName":"Jack", "LastName":"Wil" }, "JAY": { "FirstName":"Jay", "LastName":"Martin" } }
```

I'm writing a HTTPS triggered cloud function that first sends Node names (JACK, JAY) and then based on selection, sends details.

For sending the Node names, I'm just wondering if there is any way/function to get all the Node names under a Child without iterating through the snapshot and collecting the names using `'.key'`

I have gone through the below posts, but they discuss the iteration logic. So posting a new question.

Getting node names from Firebase database based on emailId match
[Getting node names from Firebase database based on emailId match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718302/getting-node-names-from-firebase-database-based-on-emailid-match)