# how to get this DatabaseReference auto generate ID to remove whole DatabaseReference from client side

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

let's say, I want to remove the whole collection/ DatabaseReference which is named -MNl6bPhPg6BNnM9NKEy, currently as I understand, with the method：

```
final roomId = databaseReference.child('/message/$room').push();
print($roomId);
```

but I got an Instance of 'DatabaseReference', so could you plz first tell me how to set this DatabaseReference by myself instead automatically? And how to remove this DatabaseReference?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: `.push()` generate a new, unique reference, so `roomId` will always point to a non-existing node. In order to delete a node, you will need to know the entire path to that node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a node, you need to know the entire path to that node. You can then create a `DatabaseReference` to that path, and call [`remove()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/remove.html) on that reference.

`.push()` generate a new, unique reference, so `roomId` will always point to a non-existing node.

So in your case that'd be:

```
final roomRef = databaseReference.child('/message/-MNl6bPhPg6BNnM9NKEy');
roomRef.remove();
```

---

Typically you should already know the key of the room to delete, as you likely loaded the data from there into your application. But if you don't know the key, but *do* know something else that unique identifies the node, you can [use a query](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/lists-of-data#sorting-and-filtering-data) to find the node.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you as always:) Now i have better understand of firebase

Comment: Hi Frank, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718395/17294750   I just want to get the name of this node, but .name() does not exists? So if i know final roomRef,  how can I get the name of -MNl6bPhPg6BNnM9NKEy? I tried getKey(), not exists; toString(), still return Instance of 'DatabaseReference'

Comment: I found a solution from docs which is snapshot.key from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot    so my way is forEach find the child snapshot, and final pathName = childSnapshot.key to locate the last part of path, is that the right solution? thank you Frank

Comment: Sounds like you figured it out with the help of the documentation @mattipeterbull. 